# With ReactJS Popup, how can I make it only show one pop up at a time?

Tags: reactjs, popup

I am experimenting with different React popup libraries. I found reactjs-popup and began playing with the codesandbox. I created a fork of the environment here https://codesandbox.io/s/pp60zjkxlj

When I click the first (or second) button, it displays the corresponding popup. What i'd like is so that when I click other button, it will display that button's popup and hide any other popups that are visible. The goal is that only one popup should be visible on screen at any time.

Is this possible with this library?

See https://codesandbox.io/s/pp60zjkxlj

Answer (score 0):

have a common state for popup when first button is clicked set the state to first button and based on the state

Comment: What's not clear to me is how to disable the any popup from working when some global state is set. I found there's two props you can set on the Popup component (1) open and (2) disabled. The disabled one doesn't seem to do anything as far as I can tell. The open prop does work when trying to trigger the Popup open/closed via some external state. However, if you click directly on the popup component, it still displays itself regardless of the value of open prop.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) where you can use a portal that sits outside of the jsx that wishes to use it.

imo it is the best way to implement a modal and i believe there's not to much need to add another dependency to your project and just create one this way that matches your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass props into the Popup to tell it when to open and when not to open.

Your component should have `state` set for each popover or be passed in props to tell the Popovers when to display. You can set in a constructor a default state and spread those before setting the new state with the new Popover open. This is how I handle modals.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      vendor: {} // Just showing my default state this gets set and this.defaultState is spread after my fetch request completes in componentWillMount()
    };
    this.defaultState = {
      isPopoverOpen: {
        // ---- Default Popover booleans can go here
        editVendor: false
      }
    };
  }
```

Actual function that controls the Popover status in the state.

```
// onClick of element would be onClick={this.handleTogglePopover('editVendor')}

  handleTogglePopover = id => { 
    const currentState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    this.setState({
           currentState,
           ...this.defaultState, // spreading default will set everything to false
           isPopoverOpen: {
              [id]: true // then the newly clicked to true
       }
    });
  };
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the response. I was hoping there was something built into the React JS Popover library that would handle this globally managed state for me but perhaps that doesn't exist.

Comment: Nope you have to manage that in your parent component or subscribe to the data in something like Redux, but that's a whole different story. I used popovers for a while in Reactstrap and ended up just moving over to modals as it was a lot of added language everywhere for something a modal gave me a better feel for.